# Java : check string match four "=" or more

Tags: java

How can I check if a string contains four "=" in a line using Java ?

For example it should match :

```
====
```

or

```
=============
```

but not :

```
===
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use a regex: `=====*`

Comment: `string.contains("====")` ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - It won't work. contains would return true for `=====` :)

Comment: @Thomas - That's an answer :). Use `matches()` with your regex

Comment: @TheLostMind it should match :

`====
or

=============
but not :

===`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, but your `contains()` would return true for 6 `=` as well

Comment: I remember when people used to post answers ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind That is what OP needed. Can match if 4 or more. But not for 3.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it would match `hello ==== world`

Comment: @TheLostMind, second example has 13 `=` and it should match that.

Comment: Ok.. Now I am confused about what the OP wants

Comment: @JBNizet `if a string contains four "=" in a line` - That's fine.

Comment: I think he wants 4 or more `=` to match, and not nything less than 4. Though I don't know if `hello ==== world` is a match or not.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify it he's looking for a string that contains four equal signs in a row, or if he's looking for a string that only contains equal signs, and at least 4 of them.

Comment: @Reimeus, there you go !! :P

Comment: Glad, I'm participated in this comment war :P Let's OP edit the question. Then we can start again ;)

Comment: Voting to close as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: You can do "====+" or "={4,}" as a regex.

Comment: @TheLostMind Since the title says "four "=" or more", it should be safe to assume that the solution should match for 4, 5, 6 etc. equal sign. Hence `contains("====")` is correct. I don't know what is unclear here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply see if it contains `====` with `yourString.contains("====")` - example:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        if(input.contains("===="))
            System.out.println("Contains ====");
        else
            System.out.println("Doesn't contain ====");
    }
}
```